# Google Analytics double listing with and without slash

Tags: google-analytics-filters

I've an issue with url with/without slash: 
https://www.example.com/mypage/
https://www.example.com/mypage

In GA, they're counted as 2 different pages, how can I fixed it with filters ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should avoid having your website show exactly the same content with two different URLs. It seems from your question that both `/mypage` and `/mypage/` are the same page. You should have your webserver redirect from one to the other (choose which one) and then your Analytics code will be correct.

It is possible to create a filter in Google Analytics if you can't change it on your server. I am not sure there is one really good way to write the filter, so I would direct you to what appears to be a decent existing writeup: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2010/12/17/cleaning-urls-google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

You can also add Default page in View Settings. GA will then merge rows and show as one row. You may want to read here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009675

[screenshot of view settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaX0H.png)